# Error while installing Discord

Tags: software-center, 17.10, snap

I had an error while installing Discord though Software-Center.

I clicked to install it, then the Software Center said there were an error, and that wasn't possible to install Discord.

So I tried to install Discord again, just clicking at the "Install" button, but this time the Software Center said "Discord Has Alredy Been Installed".

Discord appears in my programs but I'm unable to uninstall it. I want to uninstall it now and install again, avoiding these errors. What should I do?

Comment: If you installed from the software-center it is presumably a snap package, you can try `sudo snap remove discord` Not sure if sudo is needed here.

Comment: Yes, it's a snap ^^^ . You can run the command without sudo, a pop-up will ask for the password.

Comment: I installed it for testing purposes only and, in 16.04, it worked. Perhaps before giving up you can try in terminal ( type discord then enter) and post the error messages.

Comment: It worked with the Videonauth answer! How can i mark the question as answered?

Comment: Do you mean you reinstalled and now it works?

Comment: Yup............

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then use the following command to uninstall:

```
snap remove discord
```

For reinstalling it use:

```
snap install discord
```

If you want to know which snap packages you have installed use:

```
snap list
```